# How to attach a motor to a blade?

Tags: motor, quadcopter, multi-rotor

The hole is a slightly too big for the motor's shaft. I thought about hot gluing them together.

[Link to picture here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d9hfdbmi342n12t/2014-12-30%2013.38.01.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: ..and please, don't really glue them toghether. Sinc you are going to fly a quadrotor it is likely to collide (sometime) against a wall or a door. If you break the blade or slightly damage it, then you must change motor + blade. Bye

Comment: That looks like a propellor. From your title I thought it might be an axe.

Answer (score 1):

Which piece is the robot? This is not a robotics question.

I have to assume since you are asking a question that shows a lack of fundamental mechanical understanding, that for its intended use, precision is not a requirement.

In that case, wrap the motor shaft with some tape until you have the tightness you are looking for.

A more appropriate  fix would be some form of [adapter](http://www3.towerhobbies.com/cgi-bin/wti0001p?&I=LXZ897&P=7).
[image]

For any real application, the propellor size is almost certainly incorrect for that motor. A [gear reduction unit](http://www3.towerhobbies.com/cgi-bin/wti0001p?&I=LXCKYE&P=0) is needed.

[image]